# Unable to connect to gRPC server in Kubernetes cluster, but can connect when I port-forward [Connection refused]

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, digital-ocean, grpc-go

Been stuck on this error for the past few days!

I have an HTTP server that is meant to connect with the gRPC server through the client. It works fine on my local machine when I start the gRPC server and start my HTTP server. However, When I try to deploy it in a cluster, the HTTP server is unable to connect with the error message `error receiving stream from timer rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.109.237.114:5996: connect: connection refused"`

What I find particularly weird is that if I forward the gRPC server from the cluster, my local HTTP server connects to it just fine. Inspecting the connection within the cluster I can see that the port is open but it still refuses connections.
[image of netstat inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtxi7.png)

Notes

- *Experiene this issue on minikube and DOKS.*
- *Built these images on an M1 mac.*
- *There is no gRPC authenticationg => `rpc.DialContext(ctx, serverAddress, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))`*

GRPC SERVER  FILE

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: x-service
  labels:
    type: xx
    service: x-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: xx
      service: x-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type:xx
        service: x-svc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: x-api
          image: x/image

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: x-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5996
      targetPort: 5996
  selector:
    type: xx
    service: x-svc
```

HTTP SERVER FILE

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: b-service
  labels:
    type: be
    service: be-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: be
      service: be-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: be
        service: be-svc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bapi
          image: x/grpc
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: X_ADDRESS
              value: x-service:5996

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: b-api-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    type: be
    service: be-svc
```

Comment: Are you sure your container isn't listening on 127.0.0.1 versus 0.0.0.0? Put another way, what troubleshooting steps have you already taken and what are their outcomes?

Comment: Hi @mdaniel! Thanks for the response. How do I make sure the container is listening on 0.0.0.0? I used netstat to get trouble shoot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtxi7.png

Comment: No one can possibly help you troubleshoot your qemu setup without you posting your qemu config, or you reading the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. There are [no mentions of that port in `qemu`](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/qemu/qemu%24+5996&patternType=literal) so I don't know how you are expecting the Internet to **guess** what is wrong

Comment: could you solve this issue? I might be in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I was running into a similar situation as you are:
"Locally you can communicate with the gRPC service via port-forward, but it fail to communicate inside the Cluster (between Pods)"

If both the Pods are inside the same cluster, you should use the service name and port-number instead of the host name. In your case this should be `x-service:5996`. If you have a namespace then it should be `x-service.<enter-namespace-here>:5996`

In the Java context, your code should look similar to this:

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
  .forTarget("x-service:5996")
  .usePlaintext()
  .build();
```

If I am correct, within the k8s cluster your pods can interact with each other using their services names (and ports). However, if you want to establish communication via Ingress, check this documentation https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/

Hopefully this helps you.